# ArrayList sum of lengths of Strings

Tags: java, arraylist

If I have an `ArrayList` of words, such as :

```
{"Java" "Apple" "Orange" "New" "Dog" "Cat"}
```

And I wanted to compute 4 + 5 + 6 + 3 + 3 + 3 as the sum of the lengths of each String in the `ArrayList` plus the 5 spaces in between the words. How would I do that?

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: plus the 5 spaces in between the words ??? what is real time use?
len += arr[i].length;

Answer (score 3):

A Java 8 version using stream:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
words.add("Java");
words.add("Apple");
words.add("Orange");
words.add("New");
words.add("Dog");
words.add("Cat");

//the actual code
int sum = words
.stream()
.mapToInt(w -> w.length())
.sum();
System.out.println("sum with space=" + (sum + (words.size() - 1)));
```

Comment: Curiously, is it going to be faster than getting sum over foreach loop ??

Answer (score 1):

Simple method like following should do the job -

```
public int getLength (List<String> list) {
    int length = 0;
    for(String str : list) {
        length = length + str.length();
    }
    length = length + list.size() - 1;
    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with Java8 you can use `String.join`:

```
String str= String.join(" ", list);
int expectedLength=str.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the ArrayList.

Add length of each element to some variable.

Add the size of the ArrayList - 1 to the same variable.

Done.

Or just copy the implementation from some of the answers here if you don't want to write your own code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code below to acheive this:

```
ArrayList<String> words = {"Java", "Apple", "Orange", "New", "Dog", "Cat"}; //assume u can init array list with these words...
int count = 0;
for (String word : words) {
    count += word.length();
}
//add spaces:
count += words.size() - 1;
System.out.println("The strings in ArrayList - words have a count of " + count);
```

Comment: You mean `count += words .size() - 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        arrayList.add("Java");
        arrayList.add("Apple");
        arrayList.add("Orange");
        arrayList.add("New");
        arrayList.add("Dog");
        arrayList.add("Cat");

        int sum = 0;
        for (String name : arrayList) {
            sum = sum + name.length();
        }

        System.out.println(sum);

        sum = sum + arrayList.size() - 1;

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```